# How can I skip multiple strings from php array?

Tags: php, html

I have the categories: `2D, 3D, Photo, Animation`, which become buttons.

How can I skip the `3D` and `Animation` from being displayed? on this particular page when running `foreach`. For example, the buttons that will appear have to be: `All, 2D, Photo.`

I tried to find a solution, but no luck.
What I managed to remove was only a string, but not multiple ones, with:

```
$key = array_search('3D',$terms);
unset($terms[$key]);
```

This is my code that I want to apply the changes to:

```
$terms = get_terms("portfolio_category",$cat_arguments);
        if($terms):
            ?> <!-- category menu, this -->
            <div class="row categories-p">
                <ul class="col-sm-12">
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter="mix_all" class="active"><?php _e("All","um_lang"); ?></a></li> 
                    <?php   
                    sort($terms);
                    foreach($terms as $term):?>   
                        <li>
<a href="#" data-filter="um_<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li> 
                    <?php  endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's `in_array`, here's a basic example:

Assuming you have the following:

```php
$categories = ['2D', '3D', 'Photo', 'Animation'];
```

And your skip list looks like this:

```php
$skipList = ['3D', 'Animation'];
```

Then your `render` function will look like this:

- iterate over category list
- if the item is not in the skip list, render

```php
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if (!in_array($category, $skipList)) {
        // Display the category button
        // e.g. echo "<button>{$category}</button>";
    }
}
```